# read from file and insert in the array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a file and I want to read this file(is big file and it has 10000 word) and I want to add word by word and add in the array and I want to count the word how many times Repeats, but I found this error when I add

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 101000   at salehproject.Array.insert(Array.java:35)

and this my code

```
public class Array<T> {
    public T[] nodes;
    int size;

    public Array() {
        size = 0;
        nodes = (T[]) new Object[size];
    }

    public void insert(T e) {

        for (int i = 0; i > nodes.length; i++) {
            nodes[i + 1] = nodes[i];
        }
        nodes[size] = e;// here my error
        size++;
    }
}
```

This class when I read

```
public class TextAnalyzer<T> {
    Array<WData> AAlist = new Array<WData>();

    private static class WData {

        String word;
        int freq;

        public WData(String w, int f) {
            word = w;
            freq = f;
        }

        public Scanner sc;

        public void processText(String filename) {
            try {
                sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
                while (sc.hasNext()) {
                    String line = sc.next();
                    String[] st = line.split(" ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < st.length; i++) {
                        processWord(st[i]);
                        AAlist.display();
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("error in loadstudends Scanner");
            }
        }

        public void processWord(String word) {
            if (AAlist.size == 0) {
                AAlist.insert(new WData(word, 1));
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < AAlist.size; i++) {
                    if (AAlist.nodes[i].word.equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {

                        if (AAlist.size == 0) {
                            AAlist.insert(new WData(word, 1));
                        } else {
                            AAlist.nodes[i].freq += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Actually I try to solve the problem but I don't understand if can any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with loop.
First

```
for (int i = 0; i > nodes.length; i++) {..}
```

variable `i` never will be greater than `nodes.length`, because is 0

Second

```
nodes[i + 1] = nodes[i];
```

doesn't work. If `i=0`, you will prescribe first element on second position, but in next iteration you want prescribe data from second position to third, but second position was overrided with data from first position. Here you need a temporary variable to copy array data.

Third

You will have problem w `nodes = (T[]) new Object[size];` You will get ClassCastException.

Your code should be something like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

public class Array<T> {
    public T[] nodes;
    Class<T> persistentClass;
    int size;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Array() {
        size = 0;
        ParameterizedType paramType = (ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        persistentClass = (Class<T>) paramType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public void insert(T e) {
        T[] tempNodes = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(persistentClass, size + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            tempNodes[i] = nodes[i];
        }
        nodes = tempNodes;
        nodes[size] = e;
        size++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to count the occurences of the words in the file. For that, you can use this code:

```
public final class TextAnalyzer {
    public static Map<String, Long> countWordOccurrences(String fileName) 
            throws IOException {
        return Files.lines(Path.of(fileName))
                .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Function.identity(),
                        Collectors.counting())
                );
    }
}
```

Comment: can you help where I put this code in class array or class TextAnalyzer

Comment: I've edited my answer. If you want to store the contents of the `Map<String, Long>` in some other data structure, you could simply iterate over the map entries. Hope that helps.

Comment: but I mean should I delete the class array or not

Comment: Yes, neither the class `Array` nor the class `WData` is needed.

Comment: but this problem because the homework should I do the class

Answer (score 0):

Simple Map should do the job. No need of class Array and TextAnalyzer

```
public class Main {

    Map<String, Integer> wordFreq = new HashMap<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.processText("test");
    }

    public void processText(String filename) {

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                String line = sc.next();
                String[] st = line.split(" ");

                for (int i = 0; i < st.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(st[i]);
                    if(wordFreq.containsKey((st[i]))) {
                        wordFreq.put(st[i], wordFreq.get(st[i]) + 1);
                    } else {
                        wordFreq.put(st[i], 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> m : wordFreq.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(m.getKey() + ":" + m.getValue());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Main m = new Main();
        m.processText("test"); I found this error can not find symbol symbol:method processText(String)location:variable m of type Main

Comment: Instead of "test", you need to pass the full path of the file containing words.